# Change max length in Multiple File Upload jquery on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I want to change the max number of files allowed to upload in multi file upload plugin of Jquery [from here](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/).
I want to change on button/anchor tag click. in same way as we set options in jquery ui options or similar something.this is file upload control and button to change max limit.

```
    <input type="file" class="multi max-2" id="fileuploadcntrl" />
<input type="button" onclick="changefunc();" />
```

This function i have used to change class name and limit the files

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changefunc() {
            var classname = $('#fileuploadcntrl').attr('class');

            $("#fileuploadcntrl").attr('class', 'multi max-1 MultiFile-applied');

        }
    </script>
```

I have used this code and able to change class name on button click it display the modified class name correctly,but actual limit still remain to same i.e.2 while trying to upload new file it doesn't disable as it should be.

Tried out some tweaks in js file but no luck.

Comment: what browser that u used? is it IE 7? attr couldn't make it in IE 7 u should try prop

Comment: @shadrachJabonir,problem is not with browser am using firefox and it showing correct class name after button click but it file limit stay same what it actually has intially.

Comment: have u try to alert after all process done in changefunc, alert($("#fileuploadcntrl").attr('class'))?

Comment: yes it has shown me updated class name

Answer (score 0):

recommend you to use `addClass` and  `removeClass` than `attr` selector for better performance

```
 function changefunc() {
        var classname = $('#fileuploadcntrl').attr('class'); // i don't know why are u doing this since you are not using this in you script...
        var $fileuploadcntrl=$("#fileuploadcntrl");
        $fileuploadcntrl.removeClass(); // removes all classes
        $fileuploadcntrl.addClass('multi max-1 MultiFile-applied');//add classes

    }
```